# How can I implement this to send_message every x amount of seconds for x amount of times? With tkinter imports

Tags: python, schedule

Trying to send a message every x amount of seconds for x amount of cycles.

I have a button that calls send_message and users can input systemFrequency and systemRunTime.

Publish_message performs the action.

```
def publish_message(self):
...#do something 

def send_message(self):
    systemFrequency = float(freqSettings.systemFrequency)
    systemRunTime = int(freqSettings.systemRunTime)
    global count

    count = 0

    if systemFrequency != 0:

        while (count < systemRunTime):
            self.schedule()

    else:
        self.publish_message()

def schedule(self):
    self.publish_message()
    self.increaseCount()

def increaseCount(self):
    global count
    count += 1
```

Not currently waiting an x amount of seconds before performing publish_message.

Comment: Sorry, you said you have a button. Is it a tkinter button? In this case my answer won't work.

Comment: It is. Is there another solution?

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you can use `tkinter`'s `after` method. It schedules a function to be called after given amount of milliseconds.

```
def publish_message(self):
...#do something 

def send_message(self):
    systemFrequency = float(freqSettings.systemFrequency)
    systemRunTime = int(freqSettings.systemRunTime)
    global count

    count = 0

    if systemFrequency != 0:
        self.schedule()
    else:
        self.publish_message()

def schedule(self):
    if count >= systemRunTime:
        return
    self.publish_message()
    self.increaseCount()
    # works if self.master is your window, change if it isn't
    self.master.after(1000, schedule, self)
    # after 1000 ms, call schedule function with parameter self

def increaseCount(self):
    global count
    count += 1
```

Comment: Do you know what the reason would be for this error? AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'after'